# How to run a custom command on visually selected text

Tags: vim, command

In my .vimrc I have the following command declared:

```
:command EscapeUnderscore %s/_/\\_/g
```

However, I want to be able to visually select a few lines and have the command only affect the selected lines. Currently I get the error `E481: No range allowed`. I've tried changing `%s` to just `s`, but this did not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-range` and `<line1>`/`<line2>` with your command. Looks like this:

```
:command -range EscapeUnderscore <line1>,<line2>s/_/\\_/g
```

See the following for more help:

```
:h :command
:h :command-range
:h <line1>
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure what to search for in vim help.